# Searching jobs by date reverts to search by relevance on selecting different page of results

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Steps to reproduce:

- Visit https://stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=front+end+developer&type=permanent&allowsremote=true&sort=p
- Click pagination link at bottom of page to go to page 2 of results

Expected behavior:

- User should see page 2 of results, sorted by date

Actual behavior

- User sees page 1 of results, sorted by relevancy.

Comment: Where have you badges gone?

Comment: @Omar He hasn't earned any badges on Meta. Reputation is shared with the main site, but badges are not.